# need help in plotting the most simple x,y graph using gnuplot through C pipes

Tags: c, pipe, gnuplot

i know gnu plot is quite a good tool and has many features, but i only need it to plot a simple X and Y graph with data values provided through the pipe from a C program

here ,i have written a simple program to plot some value, it is working fine in some systems, but it is not working on mine!!

yes,i did install the gnuplot an hour ago on my ubuntu by apt-get ,still no graph pops up after this program executes,please help me make it work and need it to be simple..thank you

here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
FILE *p = popen("gnuplot -persist","w");
fprintf(p,"plot 'data.dat' with linespoints\n");
fprintf(p,"%d\t%d\n",100,200);
fprintf(p,"%d\t%d\n",200,400);
fprintf(p,"%d\t%d\n",300,600);
fprintf(p,"e\n");
fclose(p);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to plot the file `data.dat` or the numbers you are passing to gnuplot in the C code?

Comment: i want to plot the numbers i pass through the pipe..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well,finally i found the bug, it was not with my program but the gnuplot..

**i had to install  gnuplot-x11 along with gnuplot 
so i made a sudo apt-get install gnuplot-x11**

now with the same above program,the graph pops up brightly...

Thank you everyone for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to plot the data to a temporary file which you need to specify to gnu plot to actually plot. Write your coordinates in the temporary file and then pass the commands.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define COMMANDS 2

int main()
{
    char * commandsForGnuplot[] = {"set title \"My Little Graph\"", "plot 'data.temp'"};
    FILE * temp = fopen("data.temp", "w"); // write coordinates here.
    FILE * gnuplotPipe = popen ("gnuplot -persistent", "w");
    int i;
    fprintf(temp, "%lf %lf \n", 100.0, 200.0); //Write the data to a temporary file
    fprintf(temp, "%lf %lf \n", 200.0, 400.0); 
    for (i=0; i < COMMANDS; i++)
    {
        fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "%s \n", commandsForGnuplot[i]); //Send commands to gnuplot one by one.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to use the special filename "-" in your "plot" command string, which tells gnuplot to read values passed over the standard input stream:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{    
    FILE *p = popen("gnuplot -persist","w");
    fprintf(p,"plot '-' with linespoints\n");
    fprintf(p,"%d\t%d\n",100,200);
    fprintf(p,"%d\t%d\n",200,400);
    fprintf(p,"%d\t%d\n",300,600);
    fprintf(p,"e\n");
    fclose(p);
    return 0;
}
```

The code in your question is ignoring the values you are passing it and displaying the contents of the file `data.dat` instead.